# SWRevealViewController conflict with UISlider

Tags: swift, uislider, uipangesturerecognizer, swrevealviewcontroller

I currently facing an issue trying to delegate SWRevealViewController panGestureRecognizer method in one of my view.

When i slide my UISlider, the panGesture interfer and open the sidemenu instead to move my slider.

i tried to delegate the panGesture and it works well, but if i quit my view and go to an other, the pangesture is not functionnal anymore, and i can't reveal my sidemenu from my second view.

My code :

```
class Search : UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var sliderprice: UISlider!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer().delegate = self
  }

 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
  }

 func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if (touch.view == self.sliderprice){
        return false
    }
    else{
        return true
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old question, I'll answer it anyways, maybe for someone coming from Google search it will be helpful.

After many hours of research and thinking, finally I was able to come up with multiple solutions to this problem.

**The Lazy**

This solution is not recommended, but working, so I decided to list it.

Before setting `self` as `self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer()`'s delegate, store the original `self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer().delegate` to a property, and when you leave the screen at `viewWillDisappear()`, set `self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer().delegate` back to the one you stored in `viewDidLoad()`. So in the end it gets back its original delegate. Tampering with delegates like this is never really recommended, but I said, it works.

**The Nicer One**

I consider this still not the best solution, but we are getting there. Find a class, a controller that you use in the whole application and gets called when you start the app. Here set the `SWRevealViewController`'s `panGestureDelegate` to this class, and overwrite the `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin`method appropriately (see below).

**The Best One - *(in my opinion)***

Now this is the best and most clear solution. 
For the time being (May, 2018) the last commit to SWRevealViewController was in 2015.

Fork the original project ( https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController ) or simply copy the two necessary files (`SWRevealViewController.m` and `SWRevealViewController.h`) and place them into a separate folder to handle 3rd party libraries. Then you can remove `SWRevealViewController` from your `Podfile`. Don't forget to fix your imports for `SWRevealViewController` where you have it.

Now you are free to modify the files. What I suggest is the following.
Go to `SWRevealViewController.m` and implement the following method:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
      shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return ![touch.view isKindOfClass:UISlider.class];
}
```

If the touched view is a `UISlider` (or a custom class that inherits from UISlider) the gesture won't begin, meaning the pan gesture will no longer be conflicted with the UISlider's pan gesture.

I seriously hope I could help anyone out there as this problem was a pain in my back for quite some time now.